# Background fill patterns in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

In my application, I will need to let user customize the appeareance of a object.
The object can have a background.

This background can be a solid one or with a predefined pattern, like the classic one:

[image]

How can I obtain this Window of predefined patterns and how should I parameter my WPF Brush to take it into consideration?

Comment: That screenshot brings back the fondest of memories :)

Comment: @BoltClock♦ it's practical. User just need to differentiate some backgrounds, it's all..